# How to incrementally create a combination of numbers and strings?

Tags: python

I have the following numbers: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` and the following commands `['open', 'start', 'finish', 'quit', 'destroy']` and I would like to create a `string` that is a combination of all of these, *always starting with a string and ending with a number*:

examples:

```
open0
open1
```

One requirement is that a string can be followed by all of the combinations of the numbers in the numbers array, but never a combination of the strings array:

```
open562
start12
start12345
//openstart //not a requirement
```

Another requirement is that it's always a `string` followed by `number(s)` followed by a `string` followed by `number(s)`

```
open0start0
open123start3
finish0start123destroy6
```

I [asked a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69350493/how-to-incrementally-create-a-combination-of-numbers) in the past but I couldn't move from there to what I am aiming at now.

One of the solutions involved using `itertools`

```
from itertools import permutations
from pprint import pprint

data = range(6)

def inc_perms(it):
    for i, _ in enumerate(data):
        yield from permutations(data,  i)

pprint(list(inc_perms(data)))
```

But I can't go from there to adding the strings.

edit: tried to clarify requirements

Comment: What are the limitations? Just *any* combination of these items?

Comment: You're not really dealing with permutations if repeats are allowed. It looks like you can have an arbitrary number of digits in a row, but none of your examples put two words directly next to each other; is that a requirement? Are you looking for any particular number of elements?

Comment: "But I can't go from there to adding the strings." Why not?

Comment: Your requirements and examples are not clear - eg. how do you get `open562`? Please be more precise and elaborate it.

Comment: Another note: this has the feel of an XY problem. Maybe you're trying to interact with an existing text-based interface... but if you're writing your own game or menu or something, you probably want something more like a list of instructions than one big string.

Comment: What actually are the rules that tell you which combinations are allowed?

Comment: I tried to write some general advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68823716/523612) for these kinds of problems, but it's impossible to give an answer for this because it is not clear as asked.

Comment: It also isn't clear: do you want to create *all possible* strings that meet your rules, in a *systematic* way? Or do you want to create *one* string that meets those rules, chosen arbitrarily? In the latter case, what are the probability rules? Should any given short string have the same likelihood as any given very long string? Should each *length category* have equal probabiilty? Or something else?

Comment: @a_guest the limitation is that this combination is always `string` + `number(s)` as many times as possible. So you can have `open` followed by any number, then you can also have `open` followed by any number followed by another string with another number i.e `open123start12` and order of which string comes first doesn't matter `start1234open02`

Comment: @CrazyChucky thanks for catching that! Yes, it's a requirement. see my reply above as it might make more sense

Comment: @DanielHao any string can be followed by any number(s) that are a combination of numbers in the array. So you can get `open0`, `open01234` and also unordered numbers such as `open425`. the requirement is always a `string` followed by `number(s)` and then that can be repeated (a string followed by a number)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I've just realised I suck at getting my context out of my head and present to other people.  genuine question: have you got any idea on how I could be more clear  here? I've tried to answer you question in the comments above

Comment: Okay, so you're looking to randomly generate one random string, correct? Should one generated string affect later ones? (For instance, do you want to avoid generating an identical string again later?) Let's call a word plus one or more digits a "segment". Can your string have literally *any* number of segments? Is there a max length you don't want to exceed? Within your acceptable range, should every possible length be equally likely to occur? What about how many digits are in each segment, should that be random too?

Comment: As far as guidance in describing your question, try to be your own devil's advocate. Look at the specification you've provided, and see if you can follow it but produce an output you don't actually want. Trying to "break" things is one of the best ways to see if you've made them robust. (This applies to code too, of course, not just verbal instructions.)

Comment: Your attempts to clarify seem to have *completely missed the questions you were actually being asked*. For example, I asked: "do you want to create all possible strings that meet your rules, in a systematic way? Or do you want to create one string that meets those rules, chosen arbitrarily?" It seems to me like it should be easy to give an answer to this explicitly. Another, simpler question: for the specific input lists you described, *exactly how many results should you get*? If your answer is more than `1` (because you wanted to choose an arbitrary one), then show your math.

Comment: "have you got any idea on how I could be more clear here? I've tried to answer you question in the comments above" Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Show *exact* inputs (you did this already) and show *exact, complete* desired output that corresponds to those inputs, not just "examples". (If that's unfeasible to calculate by hand, use simpler inputs.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want something random you can use the random function to generate the output string, something like

```
def random_select(input,n):
    a = [int(i) for i in str(random.random())[2:n*2+2]]
    result = ""
    while(a):
        i = a.pop() % len(input)
        j = a.pop() % len(input[i])
        result += str(input[i][j])
    return result

a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = ['open', 'start', 'finish', 'quit', 'destroy']

print(random_select((a,b),5))
# note the first parameter is a tuple of your two or more arrays
# these second parameter is the number of elements you want to get the two arrays
# you can use a random number for the second parameter as well
# like int(random.random()*10)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first part use `itertools.product`:

```
nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
strgs = ['open', 'start', 'finish', 'quit', 'destroy']

from itertools import product

list(map(''.join, product(strgs, map(str, nums))))
```

Output:

```
['open0',
 'open1',
 'open2',
 'open3',
 'open4',
 'open5',
 'open6',
 'start0',
 'start1',
 ...
]
```

The second part is just a variation on this, you can use the previous output as a new input. **Warning products will increase the size of the output quite quickly so you might want to first subset a random sample of the data.**